# Delphi Firemonkey "Broken Pipe" Exception

Tags: android, delphi, printing, bluetooth, firemonkey

**Story:** My application is designed for mobile platforms and has own connection with Bluetooth dot matrix printer to print some invoice and documents on area or field. Some of android devices are working great but some of them always throwing broken pipe exception when users try to print something.

**Process:**

1. I used **TBluetoothManager** and **TBluetoothDeviceList** for getting paired devices list and I stored all paired devices in config ini files.
2. When user wants to print, I init connection with the device which is ready for printing and then I send invoice line-by-line to **TBluetoothSocket** object.
3. I change my each line to Byte Array with this function;

`function StrToByteArr(strData: String): TArray<Byte>;
var
  eEncoding: TEncoding;
begin
  eEncoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(857);
  Result := eEncoding.GetBytes(strData);
end;`

Then I send my values as Byte Array to **`TBluetoothSocket.SendData(Byte>) Method`**

**Problem:** I tried to print my values with 10+ different devices and success rate is not good enough (8/20 devices are works fine). What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is using **Androidapi.JNI.BluetoothAdapter.pas** library to handle all these configurations directly from Delphi codes.
It has **JBluetoothSocketClass** and it works fine!

-

Convert your string values to Byte JavaArray

```
function StringToJA(Data: String): TJavaArray<Byte>;
var
  X: integer;
  len: integer;
begin
  len := Length(Data);
  Result := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(len);
  for X := 0 to len do
  begin
    Result.Items[X] := Ord(Data[X]);
  end;
end;
```

**Output Stream usage**

```
  oStream := Sock.getOutputStream;
  text := CHR(15) + ' ------  ----- HELLO WORLD ----- ------'
                 + CHR(10) + CHR(13);
  oStream.write(StringToJA(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function StringToJA(Data: String): TJavaArray<Byte>;
var
  X: integer;
  len: integer;
begin
  len := Length(Data);
  Result := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(len);
  for X := 0 to len do
  begin
    Result.Items[X] := Ord(Data[X]);
  end;
end;
```

Some times using the function above, the application crashes without any excepition

Using the function below, the application print data and works fine

```
function StringToJA(Data: String): TJavaArray<Byte>;
var
  Arr: TBytes;
  len: integer;
begin
  Arr := TEncoding.Default.GetBytes(Data);
  len := Length(Arr);
  Result := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(len);
  if len > 0 then Move(Arr[0], Result.Data^, len);
end;
```